# $\exists$- introduction rule

Tags: logic

My reference is "A Course on Mathematical Logic" by S.M. Srivastava.

This question is about a certain inference rule for proofs in first order logic. If $L$ is a first order language and $T$ is a theory written in $L$, you define a proof in $T$ to be a finite string of formulas $A_1,\dots,A_n$ such that each of the $A_i$ is either a logical axiom (like $\neg A\vee A$ for any forumla $A$), a non-logical axiom (a formula of $T$, an 'axiom' of $T$) or obtained from one or more of the $A_1,\dots,A_{i-1}$ by one of the rules of inference listed in the book. One such rule is the 'intuitive' *expansion rule* which states that if you've written down $A$ in your proof, and $B$ is any formula you like, you are allowed to write down $B\vee A$.

There is one such rule that I don't quite understand, the $\exists$-*introduction rule* : if you have already written down $A\rightarrow B$, and $x$ is a variable that is not free in $B$, then you can write down $\exists x A\rightarrow B$.

There is a little ambiguity, but I believe what is meant is $(\exists x A)\rightarrow B$.

> What is the meaning of this? Can it be motivated by concrete examples? Why is it 'true'?

Comment: I'm confused. You talk about an $\exists$-introduction rule but that's not what you have written down. Are you sure that's what the book says?

Comment: @Zhen Lin you are right, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I call the rule you are talking about *existential instantiation*. It captures the following idea: suppose you want to prove $q$, which does not depend on $x$, but in order to do so, you need to assume $p(x)$, which does depend on $x$. Then, as long as there is *some* $x$ such that $p(x)$ holds, $q$ is true, and it doesn't matter what that $x$ is: in other words, $(\exists x . \, p(x)) \to q$.

Here is a simple example. Let $q(y)$ be the proposition ‘$y$ is a non-empty set’. Let $p(x, y)$ be the proposition $x \in y$. Then, it is evident that $p(x, y) \to q(y)$. But $q(y)$ does not depend on $x$, so we may deduce that $(\exists x . \, p(x, y)) \to q(y)$.

But perhaps you prefer some elementary number theory. So let $q(y)$ be the proposition ‘$y \ne 1$ and $y$ is composite’. Let $p(x, y)$ be the proposition ‘$x \ne 1$ and $x \ne y$ and $x$ divides $y$’. Then certainly $p(x, y) \to q(y)$, so $(\exists x . \, p(x, y)) \to q(y)$.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks :)

Comment: Can you maybe shed some light as to why we want $x$ not to be free within $q$?

Comment: Heuristically, this is because $\exists x$ binds $x$, so it is no longer meaningful in context. Concretely, let $q(x)$ be the proposition $x = 1$, and $p(x)$ be the proposition $x = 1$. Then obviously $p(x) \to q(x)$, but it is certainly not true that $(\exists x . \, p(x)) \to q(x)$. I believe a neater presentation, without invoking variable names or the free/bound distinction, is possible, but I have not found one myself.

Answer (score 1):

Following *Zhen Lin's* Example , you must take in account that inference rules mut be **sound**, i.e. for every interpretation of the language, if the premisses of the rule are true in that interpretation, so also is the conclusion.

Take the $\exists$-intro rule : if $A(x) \rightarrow B$ then $\exists xA(x) \rightarrow B$ , and remove the restriction on $x$ being free in $B$.

Let your interpretation having domain the set of natural nambers and let $E()$ a predicate constant of your language standing for "$x$ is Even".

Consider the formula : $E(x) \rightarrow \lnot x = 1$ and "interpret" it, i.e. consider an assignement of objects of the domain (numbers) to the free variables in your formula (the $x$).

If the value assigned to $x$ is $1$, then Even$(1)$ is false, and so the conditional is true.

If the value assigned to $x$  is a number $n$ different from $1$, then $\lnot n = 1$ is true, and again the conditional is true.

So, in this interpretation, the formula is always true.

What happens with the conclusion ? It is now : $\exists xE(x) \rightarrow \lnot x = 1$.

Of course, $\exists xE(x)$ is true, because there are even numbers, but the number $1$ is not different from itself; so $\exists xE(x) \rightarrow \lnot x = 1$ is not always true in this interpretation .

Conclusion : the rule stated without restriction on free vars would license false conclusion from true premisses, i.e. is **not sound**.